# Complexity of DFA intersection in this specific case?

Tags: automata-theory, regular-language, dfa

In general, the size of the DFA that recognizes the intersection of $n$ languages is exponential in $n$. However, in my case I am computing the intersection of a very restricted subset of possible languages. I am curious if this weakens the lower complexity bound.

With an alphabet $\Sigma$, for the $i$th language, I have set $A_i \subseteq \Sigma$ and another set $B_i \subseteq \Sigma$. The $i$th language $L_i$ consists of strings containing any number of symbols in $A_i$, followed by one symbol in $B_i$, followed by any number of symbols in $\Sigma$. I would like to find a DFA that recognizes $L = L_1 \cap L_2 \cap ... \cap L_n$.

Do these restrictions on the input languages eliminate the exponential lower bound?

Comment: Are $A_i$ and $B_i$ disjoint?

Comment: @Gamow I think it would recognize the same strings either way, because after one element from $B_i$ appears the rest of the string can be anything. Imagine dividing up the string into three parts, $a,b$ and $\sigma$, with each part being composed of symbols belonging to the subsets $A,B$ and $\Sigma$ respectively. Removing an element from $A$ that is in $B$ would make $b$ bigger and $a$ smaller in some cases, but the same strings would be recognized.

Comment: What about the following situation: Let $\Sigma=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ be an alphabet of size $n$. Set all $A_i=\Sigma$, and set $B_i=\{a_i\}$.

Comment: In that case, $L_i$ includes any string that contains $a_i$ somewhere. Now, consider $L'_i$, defined with $A_i = \Sigma - {a_i}$ and $B_i = {a_i}$. $L'_i$ would also include every string that contains $a_i$ somewhere. The intersections of the languages would be the same because the languages are the same.

Comment: Oh, right, I see now. Your example is size $2^n$. (Edit: I tried to reduce the $n!$ original and I found out that it was shaped like a hypercube.)

Comment: Neat!  Without thinking too deeply into it, $O(2^n)$ sounds like it could possibly be an upper bound.

Comment: What about determining if the intersection is non-empty?  How efficiently can we answer this question?

Comment: Note: If for every $i$, $A_i \cup B_i = \Sigma$ and $B_i \neq \emptyset$, then the intersection is guaranteed to be non-empty.

Comment: Maybe it's easier than I thought.  I'm thinking it can be solved in $\vert \Sigma \vert \cdot n^2$ time or possibly better.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking.  Keep a list $S \subseteq [n]$ where $i \in S$ if $L_i$ has not yet been satisfied.  For every $x \in \Sigma$, go through each $i \in S$. 
 Check if $x \in A_i$ and if $x \in B_i$.  If for every $i \in S$, $x \in A_i \cup B_i$, then remove every $j$ from $S$ such that $x \in B_j$.  Repeat until $S$ is empty or every $x \in \Sigma$ fails to remove more elements from $S$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The precise bound is $2^n$. The lower bound was given in the comments: the state complexity of $A^*a_1A^* \cap \dotsm \cap A^*a_nA^*$ is $2^n$.
For the upper bound, it suffices to observe that if $B$ and $C$ are subsets of the alphabet $A$, then the language $B^*CA^* = (B - C)^*CA^*$ is recognised by a 2-state DFA. It follows that the complexity of the intersection of $n$ such languages is upper bounded by $2^n$.